# QuickSort - Different Implementation not working

Tags: c, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, quicksort

So I tried implementing a `quicksort` algorithm but instead of setting `i, j` both at `start`, I set `j` at `end - 1` (because at `end` I have the `pivot`). I also used the `3-median` to choose the `pivot`. Basically, I do the same thing as the average `quicksort` algorithm, except reversed, and I return the `pivot` at `i` once `i` and `j` *cross*. But it doesn't work, *why?*

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

int median(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int center = (left + right) / 2;

    if (arr[left] > arr[center]) {
        swap(&arr[left], &arr[center]);
    }
    if (arr[left] > arr[right]) {
        swap(&arr[left], &arr[right]);
    }
    if (arr[center] > arr[right]) {
        swap(&arr[center], &arr[right]);
    }
    swap(&arr[center], &arr[right]);

    return arr[right];
}

int partition(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    int pivot = median(arr, left, right);
    int i = left; int j = right - 1;
    for (;;) {
        while (arr[i++] < pivot);
        while (arr[j--] > pivot);
        if (i < j) {
            swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    
    swap(&arr[i], &arr[right]);
    return i;
}

void quicksort(int arr[], int left, int right) {
    if (left < right) {
        int piv_pos = partition(arr, left, right);
        quicksort(arr, left, piv_pos - 1);
        quicksort(arr, piv_pos + 1, right);
    }
}

int main() {
    int test[] = { 2, 7, 1, 4, 10, 6, 12, 19, 26, 0, 40, 5, 39, 16, 0, 3, 4, 12, 2, 8 };
    int size = sizeof(test) / sizeof(test[0]);
    quicksort(test, 0, size - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", test[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
16
0
7
12
4
2
19
3
5
39
8
10
6
40
0
1
26
4
12
2
```

Comment: `while(arr[i++]<pivot);` If `arr[left]` is greater than the pivot, this loop will set `i` to `left+1`.

Comment: _Just a guess:_ Your partitioning scheme looks like a Hoare variant. But, your quicksort routine looks like Lomuto. So, I'll assume Hoare. So, partitition would be slightly different: `int piv_pos = partition(arr, left, right); quicksort(arr, left, piv_pos); quicksort(arr, piv_pos+1, right);` (i.e. first call is `piv_pos` and _not_ `piv_pos-1`)

Comment: @user3386109 Thank you! `while(arr[i]<pivot){i++;} while(arr[j]>pivot){j--;}` resolved the issue! @Craig Estey doing that I get a segmentation fault :/